# How can I put variable of one function into another function?

Tags: python, function, variables, nested

I am getting the error 'NameError: name 'card_dealer_1' is not defined' while it is defined in function (Blackjack_loop) that runs before the function (Blackjack) which gives the error.

I have used the globe function and I have tried to put 'card_dealer_1' as input into the second function. Both didn't work.

To show a bit of my coding,

```
def Blackjack_loop():
    wallet = 1000
    while play == True:
        if wallet <= 0:
            print("\nMy apologies. You have run out of cash and cannot continue the game. Please restart if you want to have a rematch.")
            break
        deck = [A, A, A, A, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9,9, 10, 10, 10, 10, J, J, J, J, Q, Q, Q, Q, K, K, K, K]
        random.shuffle(deck)
        bet = input("\nHi! The dealer here is speaking. May I know how much money you want to bet?\n$")
        card_dealer_1 = random.randint(0, 51)
        card_dealer_1 = deck[card_dealer_1]
        deck.remove(card_dealer_1)

        card_dealer_2 = random.randint(0, 50)
        card_dealer_2 = deck[card_dealer_2]
        deck.remove(card_dealer_2)
```

## and function two

```
def Blackjack():
    dealer = [card_dealer_1, card_dealer_2]
    player = [card_player_1, card_player_2]
    if input("\nDo you want another card? Type 'y' or 'no'\n") == 'y':
        card_player = random.randint(0, X)
        card_player = deck[card_player]
        if card_player == 11:
            A = int(input("You have drawn an A. Do you want the value to be 11 or 1? An invalid input automatically results into 11.\n"))
            if A == 1:
                A = 1
            else:
                A = 11
        deck.remove(card_player)
        card_player.append(player)
        X -= 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: I can't use the return function as I need it to run the rest of the coding. Obviously, if there is no other way, I will have to adjust it and use the return function.

Comment: Return the value from the first function, then pass it as an argument to the second function.

Comment: Alternatively, declare `card_dealer_1` as a global variable with `global card_dealer_1`

Comment: you could make it a class so that those values are shared in the class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `classes` in this case like this:

```
class name:

def Blackjack_loop(self):
    wallet = 1000
    while play == True:
        if wallet <= 0:
            print("\nMy apologies. You have run out of cash and cannot continue the game. Please restart if you want to have a rematch.")
            break
        deck = [A, A, A, A, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9,9, 10, 10, 10, 10, J, J, J, J, Q, Q, Q, Q, K, K, K, K]
        random.shuffle(deck)
        bet = input("\nHi! The dealer here is speaking. May I know how much money you want to bet?\n$")
        self.card_dealer_1 = random.randint(0, 51)
        self.card_dealer_1 = deck[card_dealer_1]
        deck.remove(card_dealer_1)

        card_dealer_2 = random.randint(0, 50)
        card_dealer_2 = deck[card_dealer_2]
        deck.remove(card_dealer_2)

def Blackjack(self):
    dealer = [self.card_dealer_1, card_dealer_2]
    player = [card_player_1, card_player_2]
    if input("\nDo you want another card? Type 'y' or 'no'\n") == 'y':
        card_player = random.randint(0, X)
        card_player = deck[card_player]
        if card_player == 11:
            A = int(input("You have drawn an A. Do you want the value to be 11 or 1? An invalid input automatically results into 11.\n"))
            if A == 1:
                A = 1
            else:
                A = 11
        deck.remove(card_player)
        card_player.append(player)
        X -= 1
```